# Make the seaborn hue legend logarithmic

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two independent linear variables and one dependent exponential one.

```py
x = range(100)
y = range(100)
z = [2**i for i in range(100)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x,"y":y,"z":z})

sns.scatterplot(
    x=df.x,
    y=df.y,
    hue=df.z
)
```

[image: x,y, linear, z hue hard to see except extreme values]

1. How can I make the hue scale logarithmic such that the pattern in the data is revealed?
2. Can I prevent the legend from showing large numbers in scientific notation?

Pyplot only contains setters for x and y axis scales, I only found how to change the legend to discrete values.